# AJAX request on local directory, but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a small application, sort of a database that can be filtered through a lot of options. I decided to create it in what I thought is the simplest way possible, HTML for all the sliders and checkboxes and JavaScript/jQuery to filter through the results. This should ensure the possibility to distribute this application without the need to compile for different operating systems or for the user to install additional software. The end-user just downloads the files, opens `index.html` and uses uses the program.

My "database" is a .txt file that is in the same directory as index.html and is retrieved through AJAX:

```
$.when(ajaxCall1()).done(function(content1) {
    ...
});
```

where

```
function ajaxCall1() {
    return $.ajax({mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', url: 'file1.txt', dataType: 'text'});
}
```

In case it's important, I chose to implement the AJAX call this way because I'm planning on expanding the database on more than one file in the future and `$.when` waits for all the AJAX calls to end and passes all the content to the parameters of the implicit function.

This worked perfectly up to a week ago (at least on Firefox, I haven't tested it yet on Chrome), but now a new Firefox update blocked the AJAX saying that the "CORS request is not HTTP".

As I said I chose HTML and JS/jQuery so that the end-user wouldn't have to install anything on his computer. I'm pretty sure that asking my potential users to install a server on their computer would discourage most of them, as well as accessing `about:config` and modifying the variable that now blocks the AJAX request (and this would also create a potential security problem, so it's also immoral).

How can I circumvent the problem with the requirement that the end-user should be able to simply download the files and open `index.html`, without the need to installation additional software or edit some browser configuration?

Uploading the files on a server, while a valid solution in theory, would give some problems because `file1.txt` is already big and will become bigger in the future. Not an ideal condition for AJAX requests, except when on a local machine, where there is no bandwidth to consider and the transfer is instantaneous.

Comment: Might consider creating an electron app from your html and js. It integrates it's own node server and chromium instance and won't require changes to what you are currently working with other than initial installation download size. Can also use a more pefomant database than txt file

Comment: As for moving to web... can use a local db like indexedDb to get instant loads and just synchronize it with your back end

Comment: @charlietfl Electron seems to require quite a lot of changes to the code. I'm looking into it, but I'm not sure I'll like it.

Comment: As I thought, Electron is far from ideal for my situation. While the AJAX request works, everything else got worse. I have none of the features of my browser and much less control overall. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with minimal change to the code, even though the solution seems sort of brutal.

First of all, I renamed `file1.txt` to `file1.js`. Then I simply added at the beginning of the file:

```
var content1 = `
```

and closed the quote at the end, so that the whole file is now a multiline text stored in a variable. Exactly as it happened after the AJAX call. I also had to replace all `\` with `\\` and there may be other characters that need escaping now.

Second, in `index.html` I added

```html
<script src="file1.js"></script>
```

And finally I removed the AJAX call above, leaving the code inside intact. This code will receive the variable `content1` directly from the `file1.js` file instead of through AJAX.

Maybe it's not the most elegant way to solve the problem, but now it works nonetheless.